# libusb_bulk_transfer() read hangs after first successful libusb_bulk_transfer() write on USB mass storage device

Tags: linux, libusb-1.0

I am trying to perform write/read libusb_bulk_transfer() on my [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) mass storage device. But after the first successful libusb_bulk_transfer() write, my program just hangs and does not perform a libusb_bulk_transfer() read. I observe that my USB device gets detached. Why am I not able to perform a read?

Following is a snippet of my code:

```
e = libusb_get_configuration(handle, &config2);
if (e!=0)
{
    printf("\n***Error in libusb_get_configuration\n");
    libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);
    libusb_close(handle);
    return -1;
}
printf("\nConfigured value : %d", config2);

if (config2 != 1)
{
    libusb_set_configuration(handle, 1);
    if (e!=0)
    {
        printf("Error in libusb_set_configuration\n");
        libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);
        libusb_close(handle);
        return -1;
    }
    else
        printf("\nDevice is in configured state!");
}

if (libusb_kernel_driver_active(handle, 0) == 1)
{
    printf("\nKernel Driver Active");
    if (libusb_detach_kernel_driver(handle, 0) == 0)
        printf("\nKernel Driver Detached!");
    else
    {
        printf("\nCouldn't detach kernel driver!\n");
        libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);
        libusb_close(handle);
        return -1;
    }
}

e = libusb_claim_interface(handle, 0);
if (e < 0)
{
    printf("\nCannot Claim Interface");
    libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);
    libusb_close(handle);
    return -1;
}
else
    printf("\nClaimed Interface\n");

char *Report_to_write, *Report_to_read;
int transferred = 0;
int received = 0;
int nbytes = 8; // As protocol suggested it should be 8 bytes

Report_to_write = (char *)malloc(nbytes);
Report_to_read = (char *)malloc(nbytes);

Report_to_write[0] = 0x01; // cmd
Report_to_write[1] = Report_to_write[2] = Report_to_write[3] = 15; // HOUR
Report_to_write[4] = Report_to_write[5] = Report_to_write[6] = 30; // MIN
Report_to_write[7] = 255; // some checksum

memset(Report_to_read, '\0', 8);

e = libusb_bulk_transfer(handle, BULK_EP_OUT, Report_to_write, 8, &transferred, 0);

if (e == 0 && transferred == 8)
{
    printf("\nWrite successful!");
    printf("\nSent %d bytes with string: %s\n", transferred, Report_to_write);
}
else
    printf("\nError in write! e = %d and transferred = %d\n", e, transferred);

e = libusb_bulk_transfer(handle, BULK_EP_IN, Report_to_read, 8, &received, 0);  //64: Max Packet   Length
if (e == 0)
{
    printf("\nReceived: ");
    printf("%c", Report_to_read[1]); //Will read a string
    //sleep(1);
}
else
{
    printf("\nError in read! e = %d and received = %d\n", e, received);
    return -1;
}

e = libusb_release_interface(handle, 0);
libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);
libusb_close(handle);
libusb_exit(NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Naming and strings look very similar to the code in Stack Overflow question *[Read/write on a pen drive using libusb: libusb_bulk_transfer()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772152)* (written by me).

Observing your code, I can only predict that you are not using the right end point addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP question is old, but the topic is still relevant.

I had a similar problem recently. I tried to replay what I recorded using wireshark (usbmon) from the manufacturer's original windows program in a virtualbox machine. I sent a command like you did, but didn't receive the answer.

Wireshark is a great tool for debugging such problems. If you have a recording of how it should be and one of your own implementation, you can easily compare them in all details.

Here are some things which might be wrong in your code:

### Wrong endpoint addresses

As already mentioned, the endpoint addresses could be wrong. Make sure that `BULK_EP_OUT < 0x80` (writing to device) and `BULK_EP_IN >= 0x80` (reading from device).

Also note that all communication starts from the host, even incoming. This is relevant for the next point.

### Message order

[image: sequence of BULK sending/receiving messages]

when using `libusb_bulk_transfer`, two `URB_BULK` messages are transferred almost atomically (host->device, and then device->host). But some drivers open the receive channel before submitting the command. My knowledge about USB is not deep enough, but I think this could also help avoiding race conditions.

If you want to open the incoming channel before sending, you have to split the receiving `libusb_bulk_transfer` into `libusb_alloc_transfer`, `libusb_fill_bulk_transfer`, `libusb_submit_transfer` and after sending the command waiting for the callback to set a flag, and finally `libusb_free_transfer`. If you are looking for code, check out the sourcecode of [`libusb_bulk_transfer`](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/master/libusb/sync.c#L279).

With my device, this was not the problem, but I left it at the end because I enjoyed having a 100% identical wireshark trace.

### control messages

After the above wasn't still successful, I also discovered some `SET_CONTROL` messages in wireshark. The relevant one in my case was `SET CONTROL LINE STATE`. I don't know exactly what it does, and it's probably something very device-specific. but in my case it was important to receive successfully from the device.

```
int sync_send_control(libusb_device_handle * dev_handle, uint8_t bmRequestType, uint8_t bRequest, uint16_t wValue, uint16_t wIndex, unsigned char * payload, int payload_size, unsigned int timeout){
    char *buf;
    int completed = 0;
    int nbytes = 8 + payload_size;
    struct libusb_transfer * transfer = libusb_alloc_transfer(0);
    if (!transfer)
        return LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_MEM;
    buf = (char *)malloc(nbytes + 1);
    memset(buf, '\0', nbytes);
    libusb_fill_control_setup(buf, bmRequestType, bRequest, wValue, wIndex, payload_size);
    if (payload_size>0)
        memcpy(&buf[8],payload,payload_size);
    libusb_fill_control_transfer(transfer, dev_handle, buf, syncread_transfer_cb, &completed, timeout); 
    int e = libusb_submit_transfer(transfer);
    if (e < 0){
        libusb_free_transfer(transfer);
        printf("error while sending control\n");
        return e;                   
    }

    sync_transfer_wait_for_completion(transfer); //from libusb-1 sources
}

sync_send_control(handle, 0x21, 0x22 /* set line state*/, 3, 0, NULL, 0, 2000);
```

### even more

In the wireshark log of the original software, I even found that an `URB_INTERRUPT` channel got opened. I didn't find any relevance for it, but it is a good example that there are a lot of possible reasons what a device might need to respond.